# How do I remove the little football icon that's appeared on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, status

On logging on to Facebook today I noticed this icon on the right of the "What's on you mind?" box:

[image]

clicking it shows this:

[image]

as (apparently) there is a football (soccer for those of you on the left side of the pond) match on today.

Now as I'm not that interested in football I can (and did) click the "x" to get rid of the second box, but how can I get rid of the football icon altogether?

I know I can wait until the match is over (as the icon disappears when it does), but there are going to be other matches and other sports and I'd rather not have this popping into and out of my status update box at apparently random intervals.

Comment: You probably can't. I'm not seeing that, but I don't live in the U.K. I've seen other similar ones for March Madness (NCAA basketball), primary elections, and other major events that I have no interest in.

Comment: Since this is probably tied to where Facebook thinks you are physically located, using a VPN to change your IP to an IP from another location would likely get rid of this, but I can't test as this doesn't appear for me.

Comment: @Folk - a couple of problems with that: a) I'd get notifications for the new area which would be even more useless that these ones and b) there might be other location based notifications I *do* want to get. What I'm after is to be able to tell Facebook I'm not interested in this type of notification.

Comment: I very rarely see these kinds of custom icons in the new post field on Facebook where I'm from, but you are correct, you would see the notifications for that location, if any currently existed. And by "type of notification" you just mean the soccer / football icon, not all icons that may show up in the new post field, is that right?